# Short Year and Month wise array data in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, date-format

I have an array below.

I want to short array in a year then month-wise. But my year is a two-digit value. Please check.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mar-17
            [1] => 100
            [2] => 2000
            [3] => 20
            [4] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jan-18
            [1] => 60
            [2] => 300
            [3] => 5
            [4] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Apr-17
            [1] => 100
            [2] => 3000
            [3] => 30
            [4] => 1
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jun-16
            [1] => 30
            [2] => 750
            [3] => 25
            [4] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jun-16
            [1] => 20
            [2] => 400
            [3] => 20
            [4] => 2
        )

)
```

In the above 5 elements, I want to sort the date ASC order. My output should be like below

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jun-16
            [1] => 30
            [2] => 750
            [3] => 25
            [4] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jun-16
            [1] => 20
            [2] => 400
            [3] => 20
            [4] => 2
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Mar-17
            [1] => 100
            [2] => 2000
            [3] => 20
            [4] => 1
        )
    [3] => Array
        (
            [0] => Apr-17
            [1] => 100
            [2] => 3000
            [3] => 30
            [4] => 1
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [0] => Jan-18
            [1] => 60
            [2] => 300
            [3] => 5
            [4] => 2
        )


)
```

I tried with the below code but it's only ascending the alphabetic order.

```
usort($data, fn($a, $b) => $a[0] <=> $b[0]);
```

Comment: You can not sort dates in this kind of format using simple string comparison - that happens character-by-character, from left to right. You need to take those values apart into year and month, and compare the year portions first. And if those are equal, then you will need to "translate" your abbreviated month _names_ you got there into the corresponding month number, and compare those.

Comment: What are those 4000, 3000 numbers? You mean short or sort?

Answer (score 0):

```
function cmp($a, $b)
{
    $monthArray = ['Jan' => 1, 'Feb' => 2, 'Mar' => 3, 'Apr' => 4 , 
    'May' => '5', 'Jun' => 6,
    'Jul' => '7', 'Aug' => 8, 'Sep' => 9, 'Oct' => 10, 'Nov' => 11, 
    'Dec' => 12];

    $prev =  $a[0];
    $next = $b[0];
    $prevArray = explode('-', $prev);
    $nextArray = explode('-', $next);
    if ($prev == $next) {
        return 0;
    }
    if ( $prevArray[1] < $nextArray[1]) {
        return -1;
    } else if ($prevArray[1] > $nextArray[1]) {
        return 1;
    }

    if ($monthArray[$prevArray[0]] < $monthArray[$nextArray[0]]) {
        return -1;
    }

    return 1;
}

usort($data, 'cmp');
print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just parse the date to timestamp insert the callback of  `usort()` function. Also convert the short hand of year.

```
<?php

$data = [
    [
        'Mar-17',
        100,
        2000,
        20,
        1,
    ],
    [
        'Jan-18',
        100,
        2000,
        20,
        1,
    ],
    [
        'Apr-17',
        100,
        2000,
        20,
        1,
    ],
    [
        'Jun-16',
        100,
        2000,
        20,
        1,
    ],
    [
        'Jun-16',
        100,
        2000,
        20,
        1,
    ]
];

usort($data, function ($d1, $d2) {
    $pre = '-20';
    $t1 = strtotime(str_replace('-', $pre, $d1[0]));
    $t2 = strtotime(str_replace('-', $pre, $d2[0]));
    return $t1 <=> $t2;
});

var_dump($data);
```